What is the Relationship Between the Poynting Theorem, Reciprocity Theorem, and Photons?
The Problem
In electromagnetic field theory, there are two important theorems. One is the Poynting theorem:
$$
-\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}\times\boldsymbol{H})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = \int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}\cdot\boldsymbol{J} + \boldsymbol{E}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{D} + \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{B})dV\tag{1}
$$
The other is the reciprocity theorem:
$$
\int_{V}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}dV = \int_{V}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}dV\tag{2}
$$
The quantities on both sides of these theorems have the same dimensions, i.e., power, suggesting a potential relationship between them.
For a photon, the photon is emitted from a radiating charge in the light source and absorbed by an absorbing charge in the light sink. The electron in the radiating body of the light source jumps from a higher energy level to a lower energy level, while the absorbing charge in the light sink jumps from a lower energy level to a higher energy level after absorbing the photon. Hence, we have:
$$
\text{Energy emitted by the light source} = \text{Energy flow propagated through space} = \text{Energy absorbed by the light sink}\tag{3}
$$
There seems to be a relationship between the Poynting theorem, the reciprocity theorem, and photons. Can we discuss this in detail?

Reciprocity does not apply at the photon level. A photon is the outcome of an irreversible process. It can, by definition, not be reversed. The mean field theory is, of course, the same as Maxwell. There is nothing new here if all you want to discuss is average photon counts.

Two Types of Reciprocity Theorems
In fact, we have two types of reciprocity theorems: the Lorentz reciprocity theorem and the Welch reciprocity theorem. The Welch reciprocity theorem is more closely related to energy and, therefore, also to the Poynting theorem.
Reciprocity Theorem
The original Lorentz reciprocity theorem is:
$$
\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2} - \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = 0\tag{4}
$$
This equation requires that the far-field electromagnetic fields satisfy the Silver-Müller boundary condition. Further, the Carson reciprocity theorem is:
$$
\int_{V}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}dV = \int_{V}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}dV\tag{5}
$$
In fact, these two reciprocity theorems can be combined into a general form:
$$
-\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2} - \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma 
$$
$$
= \int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2} - \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1})dV\tag{6}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is any closed surface. This general form of the reciprocity theorem can be derived from two sets of Maxwell’s equations corresponding to two different current sources, $\boldsymbol{J}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{J}_{2}$.
Exercise: Prove the general reciprocity theorem using the above Maxwell’s equations. Hint: This reciprocity theorem is in the frequency domain, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rightarrow j\omega$ can be considered.
Welch Time-Domain Reciprocity Theorem
The Welch reciprocity theorem was discovered by Welch in 1960 and is given by:
$$
-\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}(t)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(t))dV = \int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(t)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}(t))dV\tag{7}
$$
Derivation of Welch’s Time-Domain Reciprocity Theorem from the Poynting Theorem
Exercise: Derive the Poynting theorem using the two curl equations of Maxwell’s equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E} & = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{B},\\
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{H} & = \boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{J}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{D}.
\end{aligned}\tag{8}
$$
Welch derived his time-domain reciprocity theorem using Maxwell’s equations. Here, I will derive the time-domain reciprocity theorem from the Poynting theorem, which better illustrates the relationship between the Welch time-domain reciprocity theorem and the Poynting theorem.
First, consider integrating the Poynting theorem over time:
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}\times\boldsymbol{H})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}\cdot\boldsymbol{J})dV\tag{9}
$$
where the energy term is dropped after time integration because
$$
\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{D} + \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{B})dV 
$$
$$
=\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U =U(\infty) - U(-\infty) =0\tag{10}
$$
where
$$
U = \frac{1}{2}\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}\cdot\boldsymbol{D} + \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\boldsymbol{B})dV\tag{11}
$$
$U(\infty)$ is the energy at the end of the system, and $U(-\infty)$ is the energy at the beginning of the system. Both of these energies are zero.
In the Poynting theorem, suppose the current $\boldsymbol{J}$ consists of two parts:
$$
\boldsymbol{J} = \sum_{i=1}^{2}\boldsymbol{J}_{i}\tag{12}
$$
According to the principle of superposition, the corresponding electric and magnetic fields satisfy:
$$
\boldsymbol{E} = \sum_{i=1}^{2}\boldsymbol{E}_{i}, \ \ \ \boldsymbol{H} = \sum_{i=1}^{2}\boldsymbol{H}_{i}\tag{13}
$$
Substituting these into the time-integrated Poynting theorem gives:
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}\sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{j})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma
$$
$$
 = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}\sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{j})dV\tag{14}
$$
Furthermore, for the current $\boldsymbol{J}_{i}$, the following Poynting theorem holds:
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{i})dV\tag{15}
$$
Subtracting the above equation from the previous equation gives:
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}\sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{2}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{j})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma 
$$
$$= \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}\sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{2}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{j})dV\tag{16}
$$
Or,
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma 
$$
$$= \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1})dV\tag{17}
$$
If we assume that the two current sources $\boldsymbol{J}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{J}_{2}$ generate one retarded wave and one advanced wave, then the electromagnetic fields $\xi_{1} = [\boldsymbol{E}_{1},\boldsymbol{H}_{1}]^{T}$ and $\xi_{2} = [\boldsymbol{E}_{2},\boldsymbol{H}_{2}]^{T}$, further assume that the surface $\Gamma$ is a sphere with an infinite radius. In this case, the electromagnetic fields $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ cannot reach the surface $\Gamma$ simultaneously. This is because the retarded wave reaches the surface $\Gamma$ in the future, while the advanced wave reaches the surface $\Gamma$ in the past. Therefore, we have:
$$
\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = 0\tag{18}
$$
Therefore, we further have:
$$
\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1})dV = 0\tag{19}
$$
Or
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1})dV = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2})dV\tag{20}
$$
The above is Welch’s time-domain reciprocity theorem. It can be seen that the derivation of the Welch time-domain reciprocity theorem considers advanced waves. Moreover, Welch’s time-domain reciprocity theorem can be regarded as a sub-theorem of the Poynting theorem. If advanced waves exist, we can consider the Welch reciprocity theorem as an energy theorem. In the engineering electromagnetic field theory community, advanced waves are generally not considered physically real. Thus, Welch’s reciprocity theorem may not yet be considered an energy theorem.
Do advanced waves exist? In physical theory, there is a group of well-known scientists who believe that advanced waves are physically real. Among them, the most famous are Wheeler and Feynman’s absorber theory (1945) and Cramer’s transactional interpretation (1986). The action and reaction theory. Dirac’s self-force problem. Therefore, we might as well accept advanced waves as physically real, making Welch’s time-domain reciprocity theorem an energy theorem.
Mutual Energy Flow Theorem
$$
-\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}(\omega)^{*}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(\omega))dV = (\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}(\omega)^{*})dV\tag{21}
$$
where
$$
(\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma\tag{22}
$$
$\Gamma$ is any closed surface that can separate the two currents or an infinitely large surface. $(\xi_{1},\xi_{2})$ is the energy flow transferred from current source $\boldsymbol{J}_{1}$ to current source $\boldsymbol{J}_{2}$.
Exercise: Prove the above mutual energy flow theorem using the two sets of Maxwell’s equations.
In the time domain, applying the inverse Fourier transform to the above mutual energy flow theorem gives the time-domain mutual energy flow theorem:
$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1})dV = (\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2})dV\tag{23}
$$
where
$$
(\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma\tag{24}
$$
Energy Conservation Law
Transformers operate under quasi-static magnetic conditions, where the displacement current is zero. Thus, the two curl equations of Maxwell’s equations under quasi-static magnetic conditions are:
$$
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E}_{1} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{B}_{1}, \quad \nabla\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1} = \boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{J}}_{1}\tag{25}
$$
$$
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E}_{2} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{B}_{2}, \quad \nabla\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2} = \boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{J}}_{2}\tag{26}
$$
Zhao discovered that under quasi-static magnetic conditions, the self-energy flow is reactive power, i.e.,
$$
\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = 0, \ \ \ i=1,2\tag{27}
$$
Or in the frequency domain:
$$
\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i}^{*})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = 0, \ \ \ i=1,2\tag{28}
$$
In this case, all self-energy flows $\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i}^{*})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma$ are reactive power and therefore do not transfer energy. The only energy-transferring flow is the mutual energy flow $\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma$. Therefore, the mutual energy flow is the only energy-transferring energy flow. Thus, the mutual energy flow theorem is called the energy conservation law.
In the transformer condition, the mutual energy theorem:
$$
-\int_{V_{1}}(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}(\omega)^{*}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(\omega))dV = \int_{V_{2}}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}(\omega)^{*})dV\tag{29}
$$
is transformed as:
$$
\int_{V}\cdots\boldsymbol{J}dV\rightarrow\oint_{C}Id\boldsymbol{l}\tag{30}
$$
$$
-\oint_{C_{1}}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}I_{1} = \oint_{C_{2}}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}I_{2}^{*}\tag{31}
$$
$$
-\mathcal{E}_{2\rightarrow1}^{*}I_{1} = \mathcal{E}_{1\rightarrow2}I_{2}^{*}\tag{32}
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{E}_{2\rightarrow1} = \oint_{C_{1}}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}\tag{33}
$$
$$
\mathcal{E}_{1\rightarrow2} = \oint_{C_{2}}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}\tag{34}
$$
Considering in the transformer:
$$
-\mathcal{E}_{2\rightarrow1} = V_{1}\tag{35}
$$
$$
\mathcal{E}_{1\rightarrow2} = V_{2}\tag{36}
$$
So we have:
$$
V_{1}^{*}I_{1} = V_{2}I_{2}^{*}\tag{37}
$$
The above equation can be written as:
$$
P_{1} = P_{2}\tag{38}
$$
$$
P_{1} = V_{1}^{*}I_{1}\tag{39}
$$
$$
P_{2} = V_{2}I_{2}^{*}\tag{40}
$$
where $P_{1}$ is the input power of the transformer, and $P_{2}$ is the output power of the transformer. Therefore, under ideal transformer conditions, the mutual energy theorem is the energy conservation law.
Furthermore, under transformer conditions, energy is transferred through the mutual energy flow:
$$
(\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma\tag{41}
$$
not through the self-energy flow corresponding to the Poynting vector:
$$
\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i}^{*})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma\tag{42}
$$
In the transformer condition, we have:
$$
\mathcal{E}_{1\rightarrow2} = -j\omega M_{1\rightarrow2}I_{1},\quad \mathcal{E}_{2\rightarrow1} = -j\omega M_{2\rightarrow1}I_{2}\tag{43}
$$
Thus,
$$
-(-j\omega M_{2\rightarrow1}I_{2})^{*}I_{1} = (-j\omega M_{1\rightarrow2}I_{1})I_{2}^{*}\tag{44}
$$
Or
$$
M_{2\rightarrow1}^{*} = M_{1\rightarrow2}\tag{45}
$$
Considering
$$
M_{1\rightarrow2}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\oint_{C_{2}}\oint_{C_{1}}\frac{1}{r}d\boldsymbol{l}_{1}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}_{2}
$$
$$
M_{2\rightarrow1}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\oint_{C_{1}}\oint_{C_{2}}\frac{1}{r}d\boldsymbol{l}_{2}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}_{1}
$$
Obviously, we have:
$$
M_{2\rightarrow1} = M_{1\rightarrow2}\tag{46}
$$
This verifies that the mutual energy theorem is indeed the energy conservation law.
So it seems that the formula (45) is self-evident, but in fact, the correctness of the formula (45) verifies the mutual energy theorem (32), and thus (45) is indeed the law of conservation of energy.
Proof of the Existence of Advanced Waves
If we consider moving the secondary coil of a transformer far away from the primary coil, a lag factor should be added to the mutual inductance formula:
$$
M_{1\rightarrow2} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\oint_{C_{2}}\oint_{C_{1}}\frac{1}{r}\exp(-jkr)d\boldsymbol{l}_{1}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}_{2}\tag{47}
$$
At this time, the energy conservation law requires:
$$
M_{2\rightarrow1} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\oint_{C_{1}}\oint_{C_{2}}\frac{1}{r}\exp(+jkr)d\boldsymbol{l}_{2}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}_{1}\tag{48}
$$
The inner integral of the first equation, multiplied by the current $I_{1}$, gives:
$$
\boldsymbol{A}_{1} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\oint_{C_{1}}\frac{I_{1}}{r}\exp(-jkr)d\boldsymbol{l}_{1}\tag{49}
$$
The inner integral of the second equation, multiplied by the current $I_{2}$, gives:
$$
\boldsymbol{A}_{2} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\oint_{C_{2}}\frac{I_{2}}{r}\exp(+jkr)d\boldsymbol{l}_{2}\tag{50}
$$
This proves the existence of advanced waves.
The Energy Conservation Law Does Not Hold Under Maxwell's Equations
Under Maxwell's equations, for any antenna, we have:
$$
\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i}^{*})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma \neq 0, \ \ \ i=1,2\tag{51}
$$
In fact, according to Maxwell’s electromagnetic theory, this energy flow is certainly not zero. Therefore, corresponding to the radiation electromagnetic fields and electromagnetic waves that satisfy Maxwell’s equations, the mutual energy theorem is at most an energy theorem, not an energy conservation law.
In the case of photon radiation, the electron in the atom of the radiating body jumps from a higher energy level to a lower energy level, radiating a photon, while in the absorbing body atom, an electron jumps from a lower energy level to a higher energy level. In this case, there is still:
$$
\text{Input} = \text{Output}\tag{52}
$$
Therefore, the energy conservation law still holds. Thus, under low-frequency quasi-static magnetic conditions, i.e., under transformer conditions, the energy conservation law holds. At very high frequencies, i.e., under photon conditions, the energy conservation law also holds. But strangely, under ordinary frequencies, i.e., under microwave antenna radiation conditions, the energy conservation law does not hold.
This is because Maxwell’s electromagnetic theory is essentially an ether theory. According to this ether theory, the transmitting antenna first transfers the radiated energy to the ether. The energy of the electromagnetic wave propagates in the ether, and when the electromagnetic wave hits the receiving antenna, part of the energy of the electromagnetic wave is transferred to the receiving antenna. The energy of the electromagnetic wave that is not absorbed by the receiving antenna will continue to propagate in the ether until it is finally received by some object. However, there may still be some energy that continues to move until it escapes our universe. Therefore, Maxwell’s electromagnetic theory is an electromagnetic wave theory that allows electromagnetic waves to escape the universe.
Nothing in this universe should be able to escape the universe, and electromagnetic waves are no exception. Zhao does not think that this view of Maxwell’s theory is correct.
Electromagnetic Theory of Zhao
Zhao’s electromagnetic theory can be summarized as follows:

Radiation must not escape the universe.

$$
\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{i}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{i}^{*})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma = 0, \ \ \ i=1,2\tag{53}
$$

The mutual energy flow theorem is the energy conservation law:

$$
-\int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}(\omega)^{*}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(\omega))dV = (\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \int_{V}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}(\omega)^{*})dV\tag{54}
$$
where
$$
(\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = \iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*} + \boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma\tag{55}
$$

In principle, the above two postulates are sufficient to solve the problem of electromagnetic field radiation.

Any current radiates half a retarded wave and half an advanced wave. These waves are reactive power and, therefore, generally ineffective electromagnetic waves because they are radiated and then returned to the source or sink that emitted them. However, the retarded wave of one current and the advanced wave emitted by another current can synchronize or handshake. At this time, the retarded wave and the advanced wave can form a mutual energy flow, which is active power. This mutual energy flow can transfer energy from the source to the sink. We say that this mutual energy flow is generated at the source and annihilated at the sink. This mutual energy flow has the properties of particles. We can say that this mutual energy flow is the photon.


The Importance of Mutual Energy Flow
According to Zhao’s electromagnetic theory, we can calculate the mutual energy flow. The mutual energy flow is generated at the source and annihilated at the sink, having the properties of particles. Therefore, Zhao believes that the mutual energy flow is the photon. Zhao’s electromagnetic theory is very close to Cramer’s transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics and can be regarded as an implementation of the transactional interpretation.
Conclusion
From the Poynting theorem, the Welch reciprocity theorem can be derived. The Fourier transform of the Welch reciprocity theorem gives Zhao’s mutual energy theorem. The conjugate transformation of the mutual energy theorem gives the Lorentz reciprocity theorem. It can be seen that the reciprocity theorem is indeed related to the Poynting theorem.
Zhao extended the mutual energy theorem to the energy conservation law. The necessary condition for the energy conservation law is that radiation does not escape the universe. Therefore, Zhao added the postulate of radiation not escaping the universe to Maxwell’s electromagnetic theory.
Finally, many details are not proven here and are left for the reader to solve as exercises. Most of these exercise solutions can be found in Zhao’s recently published book: “Electromagnetic Wave Theory of Photons”.
